# Wallpaper manager crashes when image is loaded with transition

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-glide, android-wallpaper

I use Glide to load the image from URL and set it as wallpaper, however when transitions are applied to glide the image loads with the transition but when the image is set as wallpaper the app crashes (when loaded without transition everything works fine)

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

This is my code for loading

```
 Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
 .load(imageUrl)
 .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop())
 .transition(BitmapTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
 .into(image);
```

And for applying wallpaper

```
Bitmap bitmapImg = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap();

            WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallManager.clear();
                wallManager.setBitmap(bitmapImg);

                Snackbar.make(view, "Wallpaper set successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(fullscreen.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```